# Where's my tag badge?

Tags: support, badges

Apparently I met the requirements for a bronze tag badge ([how-to](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to)) a few days ago (I think around Wednesday or Thursday; it's now Sunday):

[image: screen shot]

I know that sometimes the update of the tag scores shown on the profile can lag by several days, but here that update has occurred: "20 non-wiki answers with a total score of 133".  And I know that some badge scripts only run daily or perhaps even every second day, but it's been longer than that.

As you can see, no badges have yet been awarded for this tag.  There might be others waiting to be awarded too (I haven't checked).

[image: screen shot]

I figure my badge will amble in eventually (perhaps it didn't want to set out on its journey before Shabbat), but if mine's running late then probably so are others in this or other tags, hence the question.

Comment: As of now, [you're the only one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/how-to/topusers) who is eligible for the [how-to] badge.

Comment: If you think there might be a problem with the system, especially if it might be affecting other badges/users, why not tag [meta-tag:bug]?

Comment: @Shokhet I usually start with [tag:support] to validate my assumptions, at which point it usually either gets answered or becomes a bug report. But maybe I'm too cautious.

Comment: Wow, I never thought I'd be first in *anything* (achievement-like) on this site! :-)

Comment: Maybe they have to forge the mold for this badge before they can start minting them and handing them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer: according to the [badge description on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/162102), tag badges require a minimum of 100 questions on the tag.  [how-to](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to) currently has 80.